# Mockito verify and mutable objects

Tags: java, mockito

Say I have this:

```
class A {
  private int a;
  
  public int getA() {
    return a;
  }
  
  public void setA(int a) {
    this.a = a;
  }
}

class B {
  public void processOne(A a) {
  }
  
  public void processTwo(A a) {
  }
}

class C {
  private final B b;
  
  public C(B b) {
    this.b = b;
  }
  
  public void run() {
    A a = new A();
    
    a.setA(1);
    b.processOne(a);
    a.setA(2);
    b.processTwo(a);
  }
}

class CTest {
  @Test
  void testSet() {
    B b = mock(B.class);
    C c = new C(b);
    c.run();
    
    verify(b).processOne(argThat(a -> a.getA() == 1));
    verify(b).processTwo(argThat(a -> a.getA() == 2));
  }
}
```

This fails on this line:

```
    verify(b).processOne(argThat(a -> a.getA() == 1));
```

because, even though `A.a` had value `1` at the time of the call, it was later changed to `2` in the body of `C.run`. That later makes `verify` fail as the object is shared between two `verify` calls.

How can this case be tested without modifying the classes under test (`A`, `B` and `C` in this case)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you *sensibly* can. Mockito keeps references to the method arguments; it doesn't copy them.

But you might be able to work around it:

```
  @Test
  void testSet() {
    final int[] as = new int[2];
    final B b = mock(B.class);
    when(b.processOne(any())).thenAnswer(i -> as[0] = i.<A>getArgument(0).getA());
    when(b.processTwo(any())).thenAnswer(i -> as[1] = i.<A>getArgument(0).getA());

    final C c = new C(b);
    c.run();
    
    assertThat(as).containsExactly(1, 2);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the early days of Mockito there was an idea to support cloning method parameters to avoid precisely the problem you describe:

[Consider cloning parameters (or only collections) if they are clone'able to avoid mutable args problem](https://code.google.com/archive/p/mockito/issues/126)

But it was never implemented:

> Comment #14
> Posted on Jun 21, 2010 by Massive Monkey
> We will definitely not change the current behavior. Clones idea is not fully implementable

Note:

- the discussion comes from 2009
- this is an issue in archived Google Code repo, not in current GitHub repo